# How to make a particular link active in jQuery Accordion Menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an Accordion Menu using `jQuery`. Here I have attached my `html` and `jquery` code below to make it for better understanding.

```
<div id='accordion_menu'>
<ul>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='product1.html'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='product2.html'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='company.html'><span>Company</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='team.html'><span>Team</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='contact.html'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>


/* Sidebar Accordion Menu
 ========================================================*/
;
(function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#accordion_menu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
          $('#accordion_menu li').removeClass('active');
          $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
          var checkElement = $(this).next();

          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
          }

          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#accordion_menu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
          }

          if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;   
          }     
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

My questing is I need to keep first submenu always open when page is loading and need to add `active` class for inner `li` when accessing its own page.

Can anybody tell me how to modify this jquery for that?

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: So you just want to toggle slide on active `sub-menu`?

Comment: @NenadVracar, I need to open `product` sub menu when page is loading. At this stage I need to click on product link to open that sub menu.

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/832/?

Comment: @NenadVracar, My expectation is something like that. But it doesn't work in my actual code.

Comment: In the products page, you want all the product <li>s to be open, in the about page, you want about <li>s to be open. Is that the requirement?